# How do I grey out fields in the calendar event entry except for authorized users?

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

How do I grey out fields in calendar event entries for customers but have it active for authorized users (entry approvers).  I do not want to hide fields unless I can activate quickly in each event and not via global setting.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://davidlozzi.com/2014/01/14/sharepoint-2013-script-hide-or-disable-your-fields/ you can disable or hide fields on your form, and you can do it based on a user's group membership. I have a nice little utility that can handle it all for you like:

[image]

Note the Start Date and Task Status are disabled